# Leave ID blank when saving entry in EFCore / Auto generate ID

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I want to create a new entry in my databse from a model.

When i automap my dto to the actual model of the database, the id property becomes: 0.
There is already an entry in the database with id 0. How do i ignore the id value and auto generate the id for the database?

```
public async Task<WikiDetailDto> AddWiki(WikiDetailDto wikiDetailDto)
        {
            WikiPage newPage;
            newPage = mapper.Map<WikiPage>(wikiDetailDto);
            newPage.CategoryId = wikiDetailDto.Category.Id;
            await _context.AddAsync(newPage);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return wikiDetailDto;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all you need to annotate `Id` property in database model with attribute or fluent model configuration.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>()
        .HasKey(entity => entity.Id);
```

or

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

As far as I remember, EF can automatically identify the property by pattern like `Id` or `SmthId`, but not sure.
Then you just pass the 0 as value for Id property (by default int equal to 0), and after calling `DbContext.SaveChanges()` the property `Id` will be generated and saved to property.

Comment: Id is seen as primary key without the annotations but when id = 0 i will get an error because 0 already exists in the database, when i set it to 1000 manually it does save.

Comment: Do you use code first approach from scratch? I mean, you have migrations and apply all model changes via migration?

Comment: This is a database first project. I auto generated the models and DBContext trough PMC